# How do I filter/sort by some expression combining two or more fields with mongoDb c# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

Assuming I have something like this as my model:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public DateTime CreatedDT { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDT { get; set; }
}

public class Model : BaseModel
{
   //more properties here
}
```

I'd like the equivalent to this Linq query written for the MongoDb driver:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Model>("CollectionName");
var result = await collection.Find(FilterDefinition<Model>.Empty).ToListAsync();
result.Where(m => m.ModifiedDT ?? m.CreatedDT > someDate).OrderBy(m => m.ModifiedDT ?? m.CreatedDT).ToList();
```

I tried this:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Model>("CollectionName");
var result = await collection.Find(x => m.ModifiedDT ?? m.CreatedDT > someDate)
                .SortBy(m => m.ModifiedDT ?? m.CreatedDT)
                .ToListAsync();
```

but I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the
> serialization information for m => Convert((m.ModifiedDT ??
> m.CreatedDT), Object).

Comment: Can you show me an example of a few of your documents in MongoDB? `db.collection.find()` in the shell

Comment: Sure, check updated question above

Comment: Thanks, looks like the issue might be the casing on `CreatedDT` and `ModifiedDT`, these need to be `createdDT`  `modifiedDT`. Try changing that around in the addFields stage.

Comment: Yes, thanks Kevin. I just realized that. I'll try as soon I have time and update feedback here...

Comment: @KevinSmith, it worked once I change the casing. The only part missing now is the one regarding the filter in my original question (LastChanged > somedate). Couldn't figure it out yet. Thanks

Comment: Perfect, I've added that last condition (which is a `match` on the aggregation) to my previous answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kinda query you'll need an aggregation query to select one field or the other based on it being null. The operator for this is [`$ifnull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) and we can append this to the document using an [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage.

I've given a little example below of how to do this in C#, at the moment in the driver there is no support fluent methods for adding fields, so we need to add it in manually with an `AppendStage`

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var db = client.GetDatabase("db");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Order>("orders");

// Clean out database to start off with.
await db.DropCollectionAsync(collection.CollectionNamespace.CollectionName);

var date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1);

// Add some data where some ModifiedDT are null
await collection.InsertManyAsync(new[]
{
    new Order{ Name = "1", CreatedDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), ModifiedDT = null},
    new Order{ Name = "2", CreatedDT = date, ModifiedDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2)},
    new Order{ Name = "3", CreatedDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(3), ModifiedDT = null},
    new Order{ Name = "4", CreatedDT = date, ModifiedDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(4)},
    new Order{ Name = "5", CreatedDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5), ModifiedDT = null},
    new Order{ Name = "6", CreatedDT = date, ModifiedDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(6)},
});
var someDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-10);
var orders = collection.Aggregate()
    // Add a aggregation stage to add an extra field to the document of LastModified which is either ModifiedDT, but if null $CreatedDT
    .AppendStage<OrderProjection>(
        @"{ $addFields: { LastModified: { $ifNull: [ ""$ModifiedDT"", ""$CreatedDT"" ] } } }")
    // Match when our new field is greater than a given date.
    .Match(x => x.LastModified > someDate)
    // Sort by our new field of LastModified
    .SortBy(x => x.LastModified)
    // Remove the field we added so we don't transfer it back over the wire
    .AppendStage<Order>(@"{ $unset: ""LastModified"" }")
    // Execute the aggregation query
    .ToList();


foreach (var order in orders)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {order.Name}");
}
// Name: 1
// Name: 2
// Name: 3
// Name: 4
// Name: 5
// Name: 6

internal class Order
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDT { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDT { get; set; }
}

internal class OrderProjection
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDT { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDT { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your answer. I have two issues with this though. First, I can't use "$unset" coz' apparently the driver version I'm using doesn't support it (I'm stuck with version 2.10.3, can't change it). I could live with that though I guess so I tried removing it but the expected sort order is not working. It's being completely ignored (check updated code in my question)

Comment: @CristianGrisolia What version of the MongoDB Engine you using?

Comment: I'm using AWS DocumentDb: docdb 3.6.0